# JavaScript/AJAX is saying "undefined" when it should show a picture

Tags: javascript, php, pdo, dom-events

On my register page, I am trying to set it up so that when somebody enters a username into the username box, it will either show a green check mark if the username doesn't exist, or a red 'X' if the username already exists. When the page loads though (the body tag is `<body on_load="process();">`), it doesn't come up with a picture, it comes up with the word "undefined".

JavaScript code:

```
var xmlHttp = createXmlHttpRequestObject();

//Create object for function
function createXmlHttpRequestObject(){
    var xmlHttp;

    //Check if IE
    if(window.ActiveXObject){
        try{
            //Setting variable equal to object for IE
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }catch(e){
            //Can't set variable equal to something
            xmlHttp = false;
        }
    }else{
    //Anything not IE
        try{
            //Want to use this object if not IE
            xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest;
        }catch(e){
            //Can't set variable equal to something
            xmlHttp = false;
        }
    }
    //If couldn't set object
    if(!xmlHttp){
        //Tell people that JS couldn't create the object (new XMLHttpRequest or ActiveXObject)
        alert("Couldn't create an object with JavaScript!");
    }else{
        //Return object
        return xmlHttp;
    }
}

//Use this attribute for body tag: <body onload="process()">
function process(){
/*readyState:
0: request not initialized 
1: server connection established
2: request received 
3: processing request 
4: request finished and response is ready
*/
    try{
        //Check if ready to communicate
        if(xmlHttp.readyState==0 || xmlHttp.readyState==4){
            //<input type="text" id="userInput" /> relates to this
            //Set variable to value they typed in
            username = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("register_name").value);

            //Creates request to send to server
            //Need PHP file, GET would be in PHP file, also can be POST, etc.
            xmlHttp.open("POST","functions/check_used.php",true);

            //Doing something to make it pretend like it's a form, for POST
            xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            //Handle server response when server responds to the request
            xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse;

            //Send request (this is used for POST, use null when using GET)
            xmlHttp.send("username="+username);
        }else{
            //Not ready to communicate, wait for 1 second and try again
            setTimeout('process()',1000);
        }
    }catch(e){
        //Something doesn't work, tell them what happened
        alert(e.toString());
    }
}

//When response received, tells what to do with it
function handleServerResponse(){
//Response done communicating
    if(xmlHttp.readyState==4){
        //Communication went OK
        if(xmlHttp.status==200){
            //Put response into variable
            xmlResponse = xmlHttp.responseXML;

            //Get document element
            xmlDocumentElement = xmlResponse.documentElement;

            //Get data from XML file
            message = xmlDocumentElement.firstChild.data;

            //Access document, put it in element on page, innerHTML is stuff shown on webpage
            document.getElementById("checkedUser").innerHTML = message;

            //Pause 1 second before communicating with server again
            setTimeout('process()',1000);
        }else{
            //There was an error with data
            alert('Something went wrong!');
        }
    }
}
```

On the register page, I have an input box with the div next to it:

```
<input type="text" id="register_name" name="username" /><div id="checkedUser"></div>
```

Finally, I have the PHP file that it is posting to:

```
<?php
require_once('../includes/db.php');
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>';
echo '<username>';
    $check_username = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = :username");
    $check_username->bindValue(":username",$_POST['username'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $check_username->execute();
    $check_username = $check_username->fetch();

    if($check_username[0] == 0){
        echo '<img src="images/success.png" />';
    }else{
        echo '<img src="images/error.png" />';
    }
echo '</username>';
?>
```

I have tried troubleshooting it, but I couldn't figure out what was wrong.

Comment: You know you could do that with five lines of jQuery !

Comment: Yup, at least close to five lines

Comment: I am going to go learn how to do this with jQuery now... :)

Comment: Give me a second, I'll put up an example!

Comment: @adeneo I wouldn't recommend telling people to fix everything, even the simplest ones in Jquery. People should learn how AJAX works even the basics, before using jQuery.

Comment: @phpNoOb - I agree, but ajax is where jQuery really makes things easy, and one of the few places where I would recommend using a library.

Comment: I don't know, having a solid understanding of the `XHMLHttpRequest` will help you far more when understanding how the AJAX process works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Listen for keystrokes in input, and check username when the input changes :

```
$(function() {
    $('#register_name').keyup(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url : 'functions/check_used.php',
            data: {username : this.value},
            success: function(result) {
               $('#checkedUser').html(result);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And there's no need to return XML:

```
<?php
    require_once('../includes/db.php');
    header('Content-Type: text/html');

    $check_username = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = :username");
    $check_username->bindValue(":username",$_POST['username'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $check_username->execute();
    $check_username = $check_username->fetch();

    if($check_username[0] == 0){
        echo '<img src="images/success.png" />';
    }else{
        echo '<img src="images/error.png" />';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Is there something wrong with my jQuery? The Google Chrome console is saying "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on'"

Comment: @TheNytangel - The version is to old, you need 1.7 or newer, and it's at 2.0 now ?

Comment: It is now saying "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined" D:

I am so confused....EDIT:It says it's coming from jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js and superfish.js....Another edit: I got it working :)

Comment: @TheNytangel - Oh, ok! You already had an older version of jQuery with several older plugins running on your site? I'll edit the code so it will work with version 1.6 then.

Comment: That would be great, we have some dropdown menus on a navbar that use one of those things

Answer (score 2):

```
  if(xmlHttp.readyState==0 || xmlHttp.readyState==4){
```

should be

```
  if(xmlHttp.readyState== 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200){
```

Comment: How do you check the statuscode before the request is sent? The return statuscode is already checked in the callback.

Comment: @adeneo read the OP question. status is send, on page load. more or less on `document.load`

Comment: I get that, but the conditional you're suggesting should be changed comes before xmlHttp.send(), and checking the response status will be hard when it's not even sent yet, and the status is returned with the response header, which would be returned in the callback function, where it's currently being checked ?